# Swift - Troubles with API calls / CompletionHandler / URLSessions

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have this long function here which makes a bunch of API calls, parses through data and returns two arrays representing a bunch of sight-seeing locations (one array holds the latitudes, one holds the latitudes). The issue I am having is determining when the two arrays are finished being populated. Ideally, I would like to be able to place

```
print("ArrayCount = \(self.latArray.count)")
```

somewhere in my code and receive a single print statement in the console reading ArrayCount = 123. However everywhere I place the print statement I get either an array count of 0 or a loop of values being printed out as they are added (1..2..3.. ... ..123). Thanks in advance!

```
func someFunction()
{
    let url:URL = URL(string: "...")

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: URLRequest(url: url))
    {
        data, response, error in

        if error != nil
        {
            print("ERROR IN API REQUEST: \(error!.localizedDescription)")
        }

        else
        {
            do
            {
                if let parsedData = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as? [String: Any]
                {
                    if let layerOne = parsedData["one"] as? [String: Any]
                    {
                        if let layerTwo = layerOne["two"] as? [[String: Any]]
                        {
                            for layerThree in layerTwo
                            {
                                if let variableName = layerThree["value"] as? String
                                {
                                    let innerUrl:URL = URL(string: "...")!

                                    let innerTask = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: URLRequest(url: innerUrl))
                                    {
                                        data, response, error in

                                        if error != nil
                                        {
                                            print("ERROR IN API REQUEST: \(error!.localizedDescription)")
                                        }

                                        else
                                        {
                                            do
                                            {
                                                if let parsedData = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as? [String: Any]
                                                {
                                                    if let layerA = parsedData["A"] as? [String: Any]
                                                    {
                                                        if let lat = layerA["Latitude"] as? String, let long = layerA["Longitude"] as? String
                                                        {
                                                            self.latArray.append(lat)
                                                            self.longArray.append(lon)
                                                        }
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            }

                                            catch
                                            {
                                                print("ERROR IN JSON SERIALIZATION")
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                    innerTask.resume()
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            catch
            {
                print("ERROR IN JSON SERIALIZATION")
            }
        }
    }

    task.resume()
}
```

Comment: Can you give a sample of the JSON you're receiving? The way you parse this JSON looks really odd.

Comment: Did you go through and replace all of your variables and subscripts to use random arbitrary names? This looks quite a bit like you're trying to parse an API response from the Google Places API.. why not just post your original code? That way it's easier for other people to help with your problem.

Comment: You can do multiple conditional bindings per `if` statement. You don't need all this crazy nesting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to do, but once I thinned out your incredibly verbose code and tried to understand it, I think the conclusion is that you'll only want to record the array counts after the last iteration of your inner loop. For example:

Instead of doing this: `for layerThree in layerTwo`

do this: `for (index, layerThree) in layerTwo.enumerated()`

Then, after you append the lat/long values, add this check:

```
if index == layerTwo.count - 1 //if this is our last inner loop
{
    //print the array counts
    print("Lat count: \(latArray.count)")
    print("Long count: \(longArray.count)")
}
```

This should work in your case. However, I disagree entirely with the execution of this simply because of the lack of portability and reusability of your code. Additionally, there are quite a few good language constructs which are being ignored. The relentless nested `if let` blocks could be reduced significantly with a few good `guard` statements. Furthermore, considering you aren't handling your errors in any catch blocks anyway, might as well just remove them and opt for a `try?` instead. One much swiftier way of handling things would be to just include a completion handler in the function itself so that the array count printing logic could be handled elsewhere. I'll include some example code of how I would clean things up:

```
func someFunction(completion: (([String], [String]) -> Void)?)
{
    let url = URL(string: "...")!
    var latArray: [String] = []
    var longArray: [String] = []

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: URLRequest(url: url),
        completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in
            guard error == nil else
            {
                print("ERROR IN API REQUEST: \(error?.localizedDescription)")
                return
            }

            guard let parsedData = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments),
                let parsedDict = parsedData as? [String: Any],
                let layerOne = parsedDict["one"] as? [String: Any],
                let layerTwo = layerOne["two"] as? [[String: Any]] else
            {
                print("JSON OBJECT DOES NOT MATCH EXPECTED PATTERN")
                return
            }

            for (index, layerThree) in layerTwo.enumerated()
            {
                guard let _ = layerThree["value"] as? String else
                {
                    print("Skip this iteration (I guess?)")
                    continue
                }

                let innerUrl = URL(string: "...")!
                let innerTask = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: URLRequest(url: innerUrl),
                    completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in
                        guard error == nil else
                        {
                            print("ERROR IN API REQUEST: \(error?.localizedDescription)")
                            return
                        }

                        guard let parsedData = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments),
                            let parsedDict = parsedData as? [String: Any],
                            let layerA = parsedDict["A"] as? [String: Any],
                            let lat = layerA["Latitude"] as? String,
                            let long = layerA["Longitude"] as? String else
                        {
                            print("Something went wrong")
                            return
                        }

                        latArray.append(lat)
                        longArray.append(long)

                        if index == layerTwo.count - 1 //if this is our last inner loop
                        {
                            completion?(latArray, longArray)
                        }
                    }
                )
                innerTask.resume()
            }
        }
    )

    task.resume()
}

someFunction(completion: { (latArray, longArray) -> Void in
    //print the array counts
    print("Lat count: \(latArray.count)")
    print("Long count: \(longArray.count)")
})
```

This could still be improved much further, though based on your question I don't see that I personally should be putting more time into constructing this for you. It would be best if you come up with a few methods of your own to build an application with more readable and reusable code.